# Boilling colloidal silver?

Tags: heat, boiling-point, colloids, silver

I have some colloidal silver that i bought from a shop. It is 18ppm, however, I need a higher PPM and I can't seem to buy it anywhere where I live.

If I boil this colloidal silver, would it make the final concentration of silver go up?

For example, If I had 1 liter of 18ppm colloidal silver, and boiled it until I only had 500ml of colloidal silver, would that mean that I now have 500ml of 36PPM colloidal silver?

Comment: Better evaporate under a vacuum !

Comment: Boiling will probably destroy it.

Comment: It may cause silver aggregation and loosing colloidal properties.